# Authorize access to Controller by Window Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

*I am novice to MVC4 environment*. And trying to restrict access to specific controller on basis of role.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{

}
```

It work fine and ask for user credentials. But I don't want it to ask for credentials. Rather it should check automatically the role of window user. And if he is member of specific role, allow him to access website page.

Can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/06/iis-75-integrated-security-with-no.html

Comment: See [Authenticating Users with Windows Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs).

Comment: Thanks! Wiktor.

@Wiktor I followed your suggestions and was able to hide window asking for credentials.

Comment: Thanks! James

@James I followed link and the link say, _Because of Windows User Account Control (UAC), when working with Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008, the local Administrators group will behave differently than other groups. The [Authorize] attribute won’t correctly recognize a member of the local Administrators group unless you modify your computer’s UAC settings._

So do you have suggestions what need to be done for making **Administrators** group work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of **@Wiktor** comment I was able to conclude to solution for it.

See my answered comment at - [Window authentication not working in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024896/window-authentication-not-working-in-mvc4)