# Window authentication not working in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis-7.5

### Scenario

User **A** can access all pages in MVC4 website except one. But user **B** can access all pages (no restriction).

**What I had done so far?**

1. Deployed website on IIS 7.5.
2. Enabled window authentication and disabled Anonymous authentication for hosted website on IIS.
3. Testing website.

**Testing Results -**

(1) When User B is logged on same system *(development system)* where the website is deployed, he can access the website without prompt dialog.

(2) But when same website is published on server *(production system)* with same settings, website still asks for credentials with pop up.

** Both of the *development system* and *production system* are in same domain (let's name it **domain.com**).

### Question

*Why is the same user in same domain is been asked for credentials by website?*

Comment: Are both users "domain" user accounts?

Comment: @mxmissile To login on both system, I use same credentials and same domain. For e.g. Domain\XYZ (login) and Pass1234 (password).

Comment: can you check if the web.config gets transformed when you published the website and the property authPersistNonNTLM is set to true

Comment: @Overmachine No! The web.config didn't got transformed on publishing. And there is no property as the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my research for **Window Authentication**, I want to conclude following lines *(also as reference for me)* -

**(1)** Window Authentication (*abbrev. WA*) will always show prompt for verifying users if you had configured WA properly.

See *anonymous authentication* disabled and *windows authentication* enabled in below snapshot.

**(2)** Even if one set **NTLM** as top provider than **Kerberos** (in IIS), the IIS will still ask for Window credentials. Snapshot show how to do that.

[image: How to set IIS Provider for Window Authentication]

**(3)** If you want to ***avoid showing prompt*** on browser for WA, follow steps-

(a) Open IE browser --> *Internet Options* --> *Security* tab.

(b) Add site to **Local Intranet** zone so that browser will send logged-in username and password to IIS.

[image: Add website to Intranet zone]

**Note -** *The above points universally apply to MVC and ASP.NET.*

**Answer to my question** *Why is the same user in same domain is been asked for credentials by website?*

Because I had set anonymous authentication enabled along with Window authentication on development system. *(Silly mistake)*.